# Refresh heavy MvcSiteMapProvider sitemap by adding new items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a sitemap with a couple of [IDynamicNodeProviders](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider).
When I add for example a news article which must be placed in the sitemap I could use the [SiteMapCacheReleaseAttribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider#caching).
What will happen if the release of the cache is done a lot (maybe a big site with a lot of changes)? 
If I understand the documentation well, the sitemap is refreshed on the next user action. But if the refresh could take say 10 seconds and the refresh is executed every time someone is editing or adding some data, then the visitors of the site are expecting a slow site.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SiteMapCacheReleaseAttribute` is meant for website administrators that occasionally add/change/delete data where the amount of time it takes to reload the SiteMap is negligible compared to the number of reads.

A better approach for the user side is to use the `PreservedRouteParameters` property/attribute to [force a match](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position#forcing-a-match) so you can reuse the same node for every record in a database table. See the downloadable demo in the article to see a complete CRUD example.

If you take this approach, you will typically need to use a visibility provider and the `SiteMapTitle` attribute to change the display of the breadcrumb trail, and your record-to-record navigation must be provided by the application, not MvcSiteMapProvider's menu (which is usually the case when you build pages to do CRUD operations anyway).

The only downside is that you don't get the automatic XML Sitemap support for search engines. In this case, you could [disable the XML Sitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747636/mvcsitemapprovider-prevent-display-serving-sitemap-xml) and either roll your own solution, or use the prototype from [here](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/prototype-xml-sitemaps) with demo [here](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_345-2).

Comment: Oke thank you for the answer. So if the administrator/contributors change a lot of data (say a world wide news company with every minute a new news article) the sitemap is reset every time. So every minute the sitemap is refreshed. What if the sitemap refreshing takes maybe 6 seconds? Then your site is down for 10% of the time? Is just try to understand how it works and what the impact of the attribute means.

Comment: This is something that I plan to fix in the next version. A lot of `MvcSiteMapProvider` was taken directly from Microsoft's `SiteMapProvider` design and along with it came its limitations. One of those limitations is that the SiteMap is stored entirely in memory in a single cache. My thought is to make each `ISiteMapNodeProvider` provide caching instructions and have a separate cache for each one, but I will have to experiment to find out how that performs. For the time being, if you need something more dynamic to produce breadcrumbs you might be better off rolling your own solution.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer. For now it isn't a problem but was just investigating if this could be a problem in the future. I like your package a lot! Everything is working fine just right out of the box. Thanks!